# Why is an empty DataFrame of dtype=str filled with "n"?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

I cannot understand why a Series created using `dtype=str` results in this:

```
In [2]: pandas.Series(index=range(2), dtype=str)
Out[2]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
dtype: object
```

but a DataFrame created using `dtype=str` results in this:

```
In [3]: pandas.DataFrame(index=range(2), columns=[0], dtype=str)
Out[3]: 
   0
0  n
1  n
```

Why strings with just the letter "n"?

Why this difference between Series and DataFrame?

And where is this documented?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This is now [fixed in master](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10658) and shouldn't be an issue from 17.0 onwards.*

---

In short, both DataFrames and Series create an empty NumPy array and fill it with `np.nan` values, but DataFrame uses the passed `str` dtype for this array while Series overrides it with the `'O'` (object) dtype.

When no values are passed in, the `__init__` method of both classes assigns an empty dictionary as the default data: `data = {}`.

After testing what type of object `data` is, the Series construction method falls back to generating an array of `np.nan` values but using Numpy's `'O'` datatype (not the `str` datatype) - see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#l175) and then [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/inference.pyx#l1139):

```
np.empty(n, dtype='O') # later filled with np.nan
```

The `'O'` datatype is capable of holding any type object, so `np.nan` causes no issues here.

DataFrame's `__init__` method also ends up using `np.empty` and then filling the empty array with `np.nan`. The difference is that the specified `str` datatype is used (and not the `'O'` datatype). The code essentially reads [as follows](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#l321):

```
v = np.empty(len(index), dtype=str)
v.fill(np.nan)
```

Now, when created with the `str` datatype, `np.empty` is cast to the NumPy `dtype` of `'<U1'` (i.e. one unicode character) and so `v` becomes:

```
array(['n', 'n'], dtype='<U1')
```

since `n` is the first letter of `nan` (`np.nan` is represented as just `nan`).

Comment: Nice explanation! Nevertheless, I think this should be considered as a bug in pandas. They can always be reported -> https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new

Comment: Thanks - I agree, it would be better if the behaviour of DataFrame followed Series here.

Comment: the ``str`` dtype should have be changed to ``object`` as the ``str`` dtype is upcast internally, so the bug is that the ``str`` should not have been propogated.

Comment: I followed joris' advice and submitted the issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9428

Comment: Great explanation. I did suspect a bug... but could not exclude the bug was in my understanding of pandas.